# :disable_with for submit button, Rails 3, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get :disable_with to work on my button. I'm using JQuery though, and the form is not a javascript implements form, so I'm wondering if theres a better way to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `:disable_with` will not work without Javascript. This is needed to modify the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

disable_with option is deplrecated since rails 3.2.5, 
So disable with should be used as

`%button.btn.large.primary{:type => "submit", :data => {'disable-with' => 'Please wait...'}} Save`

Please refer to  [api documentation](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/submit_tag)